# Changing shiny conditionalPanel based on Checkbox Input

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

**What I Want**

I'm building a shiny app that has several generic `conditionalPanels`, each of them being displayed dependent on the input coming from one major checkbox.
In previous questions I only found conditional panels with a single condition.

Let's say the major checkbox can output any values from 1 to 5, allowing for multiple choice.

A single condition for the checkbox value "1" would be:

```
conditionalPanel(condition='input.in_test==1'...
```

**The Problem**

Now, I want to fit this to the multiple choice options of the checkbox.
What I need is the javascript equivalent of R's `%in%` operator in combination with the right datatype.
I found the method `contains()`, which doesn't work, because I probably got the datatype wrong as it probably doesn't equal R's vector type.
Here's what I've got for checkbox values 1 and 2:

```
conditionalPanel(condition='if(Arrays.asList(input.in_test).contains(1,2))'
```

So, what's the correct way to translate R's `%in%` operator to this dynamic piece of Java code to make it work in the `conditionalPanel`?
Thank you for your help!

**Example**

Here's a minimal working example of what I'm trying to do, with just one condition:

```
sapply(c("tidyverse","shiny","DT"),require,character.only=T)

# helper function for choices
shiny_choices <- function(vector){
  tibble(names=vector) %>%
    mutate(val=1:nrow(.)) %>%
    deframe()
}

# shiny ui
ui <- fluidPage(
  title="This is a test",
  titlePanel(strong("Test")),
  sidebarLayout(
    position="left",
    # Funktions-Panel
    sidebarPanel(
      
      # main checkbox
      fluidRow(
        checkboxGroupInput("in_check_all","Selection",choices=shiny_choices(colnames(iris)),selected=NULL)
      ),
      
      # generic input checkboxes
      lapply(colnames(iris),function(y){
        temp <- shiny_choices(colnames(iris))
        #XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        conditionalPanel(condition=paste0("input.in_check_all==",temp[y]), # this is the critical line that needs to be adapted
        #XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
                         fluidRow(
                           checkboxGroupInput(paste0("in_check_",temp[y]),
                                              y, 
                                              choices=sort(unique(iris %>% select(y))[[1]]),
                                              selected=NULL)
                         )
        )
      }),
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("out_table")
    )
  )
)

# shiny server
server <- function(input,output,session){
  output$out_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    
    # filter data dependent on input
    x <- iris # %>% ...
    
    DT::datatable(x)
  })
  
}

# app
shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is javascript's (not Java) `includes()`.
The passed values are strings, so we also have to quote them:

```
condition=paste0("input.in_check_all.includes(\"",temp[y],"\")"),
```